# Event bubbling issue: click function does not wait for blur function containing observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, event-bubbling, event-propagation

I am have a modal which contains some inputs. Those inputs are validated on blur, which includes making a call to an endpoint and subscribing to it to get whether or not the input is valid/invalid.

The problem is when entering in some data on this input to validate, and remaining focused on the input element (not invoking blur), after clicking to submit the form (which should invoke blur first, and then the click event), it will occasionally not wait for the endpoint and subscription to complete, therefore submitting an invalid input.

Is there any way to tell the click event or the function tied to the click event to wait for the subscription from the blur function to complete?

Comment: If you have a dialog, then I would do this: make the button be set to type=button. In the submit, assuming it sends the whole submission event, do e.preventDefault(). Send the request and wait for response, while response is inflight have a boolean that is set to true/false depending on if the request is still in flight or not